# Form Validation for a React Native App

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to validate email address and password of a user while login. I tried to use stateless form but it doesn't seem to work with current version of React Native. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-stateless-form` is not supporting react native +0.25. You can use other fork of project, for example [ms88privat](https://github.com/ms88privat/react-native-stateless-form) fork.

**update:**

Install it with this command:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/ms88privat/react-native-stateless-form
```

Comment: It is the same as the stateless form.

Comment: It's not possible, it's better to check module in the `node_modules` folder. Is it same as the GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes the both are the same repo.

Comment: The first lines of `node_modules/react-native-stateless-form/StatelessForm.js` are `import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import { Platform, ScrollView, View } from 'react-native'`. right?

Comment: where do i import <Stateless Form> tag?

Comment: I'm not saying import it. Just check if the file `node_modules/react-native-stateless-form/StatelessForm.js` in your project folder equivalent to https://github.com/ms88privat/react-native-stateless-form/blob/master/StatelessForm.js

Comment: so i updated my 'node_modules/react-native-stateless-form/StatelessForm.js'. But i am still getting the same error. Do i need to change something else too?

Comment: It's a bad idea to change `node_modules` content. install the GitHub version, as answer update.