# Validation in React Native

Tags: react-native

**Error:** There is an error while having a validation on the email field that works fine for the first time but it shows nothing the second time in the error fields.

I created a login form using react-native and I want to validate every field but I don't know how to do it. I'm quite new to react-native so I want to ask anyone for help. Form validation should show an error under the following conditions:

- Input form is empty
- Email text isn't email form.
- Password text does not satisfy the conditions above.
- If the Input form has errors the login button should be disabled.
- If the Input form doesn't have any errors, show an alert to inform login success

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Avatar,
  Center,
  Image,
  Text,
  Input,
  Icon,
  Button,
  Stack,
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
  Flex,
} from "native-base";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Main = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    emailError: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const emailValidator = () => {
    if (state.email == "") {
      setState({ emailError: "Email Field canot be empty" });
    } else {
      setState({ emailError: "" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <LinearGradient height="100%" colors={["#4c669f", "#3b5998", "#192f6a"]}>
      <View>
        <Center>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/man.png")}
            alt="Logo"
            style={styles.image}
          />
          <Text fontSize="4xl" style={styles.title}>
            Login Form
          </Text>

          <Input
            placeholder="Email"
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setState({ password: text });
            }}
            onBlur={() => emailValidator()}
            variant="rounded"
            marginX={10}
            marginY={5}
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<AntDesign name="user" size={24} />}
                size={5}
                ml="2"
                color="red.900"
              />
            }
          />
          <Text style={styles.error}>{state.emailError}</Text>
          <Input
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setState({ email: text });
            }}
            variant="rounded"
            marginX={10}
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<Entypo name="lock-open" size={24} />}
                size={5}
                ml="2"
                color="red.900"
              />
            }
          />
          <Button
            colorScheme="primary"
            mt={7}
            fontSize={20}
            size="lg"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("hello");
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Center>
        <Center>
          <Stack direction="row" space="2" mt={6}>
            <Checkbox size="sm" color="blue.50">
              <Text fontSize="md" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                Remember Password
              </Text>
            </Checkbox>
            <Text fontSize="md" ml={10} style={styles.forget}>
              Forget Password
            </Text>
          </Stack>
          <Divider mt={5} width={350} />

          <Text style={{ paddingTop: 10, fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}>
            If you don't Have an accout ?
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.areadyButton}>
            <Text style={styles.alreadyText}>Create An Account</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Divider w={290} bg="indigo.500" thickness={4} />
          <Text fontSize="md" style={styles.other}>
            Or Login With
          </Text>
          <Flex direction="row" h="58" p="4">
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <AntDesign name="google" size={25} color="red" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Divider
              bg="emerald.500"
              thickness="5"
              mx="3"
              orientation="vertical"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="facebook" size={25} color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Divider
              bg="indigo.500"
              thickness="5"
              mx="3"
              orientation="vertical"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="twitter" size={25} color="blue" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Flex>
        </Center>
      </View>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};

export default Main;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    borderRadius: 100,
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  title: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  areadyButton: {
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  alreadyText: {
    padding: 15,
    paddingLeft: 30,
    paddingRight: 30,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    color: "#397eed",
    borderRadius: 35,
  },
  createAccountButton: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  createAccountText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 19,
  },
  texts: {
    color: "white",
  },
  forget: {
    color: "white",
  },
  other: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "orange",
  },
  error: {
    color: "red",
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form Validation for a React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654629/form-validation-for-a-react-native-app)

Comment: No, Read the Error that I have given at the top of the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code or https://snack.expo.dev/jccB3ldkt

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import {
  Avatar,
  Center,
  Image,
  Text,
  Input,
  Icon,
  Button,
  Stack,
  Checkbox,
  Divider,
  Flex,
  NativeBaseProvider
} from "native-base";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Main = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: "",
    emailError: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const emailValidator = () => {
    if (state.email == "") {
      setState({...state, emailError: "Email Field canot be empty" });
    } else {
      setState({...state, emailError: "" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider> 
    <LinearGradient height="100%" colors={["#4c669f", "#3b5998", "#192f6a"]}>
      <View>
        <Center>
          <Image
            source={''}
            alt="Logo"
            style={styles.image}
          />
          <Text fontSize="4xl" style={styles.title}>
            Login Form
          </Text>

          <Input
            placeholder="Email"
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setState({ email: text });
            }}
            onBlur={() => emailValidator()}
            variant="rounded"
            marginX={10}
            marginY={5}
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<AntDesign name="user" size={24} />}
                size={5}
                ml="2"
                color="red.900"
              />
            }
          />
          <Text style={styles.error}>{state.emailError}</Text>
          <Input
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              setState({ password: text });
            }}
            variant="rounded"
            marginX={10}
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<Entypo name="lock-open" size={24} />}
                size={5}
                ml="2"
                color="red.900"
              />
            }
          />
          <Button
            colorScheme="primary"
            mt={7}
            fontSize={20}
            size="lg"
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("hello");
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Center>
        <Center>
          <Stack direction="row" space="2" mt={6}>
            <Checkbox size="sm" color="blue.50">
              <Text fontSize="md" style={{ color: "white" }}>
                Remember Password
              </Text>
            </Checkbox>
            <Text fontSize="md" ml={10} style={styles.forget}>
              Forget Password
            </Text>
          </Stack>
          <Divider mt={5} width={350} />

          <Text style={{ paddingTop: 10, fontWeight: "bold", color: "white" }}>
            If you don't Have an accout ?
          </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.areadyButton}>
            <Text style={styles.alreadyText}>Create An Account</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Divider w={290} bg="indigo.500" thickness={4} />
          <Text fontSize="md" style={styles.other}>
            Or Login With
          </Text>
          <Flex direction="row" h="58" p="4">
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <AntDesign name="google" size={25} color="red" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Divider
              bg="emerald.500"
              thickness="5"
              mx="3"
              orientation="vertical"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="facebook" size={25} color="white" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Divider
              bg="indigo.500"
              thickness="5"
              mx="3"
              orientation="vertical"
            />
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Feather name="twitter" size={25} color="blue" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </Flex>
        </Center>
      </View>
    </LinearGradient>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};

export default Main;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    height: 110,
    width: 110,
    borderRadius: 100,
    marginTop: 25,
  },
  title: {
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  areadyButton: {
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  alreadyText: {
    padding: 15,
    paddingLeft: 30,
    paddingRight: 30,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "white",
    color: "#397eed",
    borderRadius: 35,
  },
  createAccountButton: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  createAccountText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 19,
  },
  texts: {
    color: "white",
  },
  forget: {
    color: "white",
  },
  other: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "orange",
  },
  error: {
    color: "red",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an emailValidator function, what prevents you from doing the same for your password etc? to disable the submit button, you can add a CSS class to it as a state and change it once the inputs are valid.

for the email for example, you can use state.mail.includes("@") etc.

The button change can be done for example by adding a dynamic CSS state and the alert can be implemented at the end of every check.

Comment: I have already done what you have said but the problem is when I'm clicking on the email field that I've validated on is working fine for the first time but isn't working as same for a second time (No validation message seen on the second time).